# Render table in html template where table-data are keys and values of some json data in Golang

Tags: go, struct, go-reflect, go-html-template, encoding-json-go

In backend I send http request to some third party site and retrieve some json data in response. Keys in the json response are not always same, but I have some idea of what they might be. For example:

Sending request to `example.com/data/1` could bring the following:

```json
{
  "File.Trimmed": 54,
  "Feature": "Generic"
}
```

While requesting to `example.com/data/2` could bring the following:

```json
{
  "File.Trimmed": 83,
  "Object.Notation": "Reverse"
}
```

My objective is to render html tables in the frontend using the key-value pairs in exact same order as they were in the response.

So the first table would be:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| File.Trimmed | 54 |
| Feature | Generic |

And the second table:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| File.Trimmed | 83 |
| Object.Notation | Reverse |

I have made the following struct to deal with this data:

```golang
type FileDetails struct {
    FileTrimmed int `json:"File.Trimmed,omitempty"`
    Feature string `json:"Feature,omitempty"`
    ObjectNotation string `json:"Object.Notation,omitempty"`
}

// cannot use map[string]interface{} because that would destroy the order
var data FileDetails
err = json.NewDecoder(res.Body).Decode(&data)
```

At this point I am struggling how to send `data` to the template and render the tables. It's possible to get the json tags (content for Column A) from the struct instance using `reflect`, but is it possible to get field names like that in {{range}} loops in the template? If possible, then how?

Or is there any better way to achieve my main objective?

Comment: See https://github.com/golang/go/issues/27179.

Answer (score 0):

> Keys in the json response are not always same

If the keys are not always the same, it's better to use `map` instead of `struct`. But as like you said `that would destroy the order`.

One approach we could try when `you have some idea of what they might be`

- we should parse the response into a `map[string]interface{}`
- and then we will create string slice which will have the key names as ordered. (You already know what will be the response keys)

And here is the sample

```
var result map[string]interface{}
err = json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&result)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

tableTemplate := `
        <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Column A</th>
            <th>Column B</th>
        </tr>
        {{range .Keys}}
            <tr>
                <td>{{.}}</td>
                <td>{{index $.Data .}}</td>
            </tr>
        {{end}}
        </table>

`

tmpl := template.New("table")
tmpl, err = tmpl.Parse(tableTemplate)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error parsing template:", err)
    return
}

templateData := map[string]interface{}{
    "Data": result,
    "Keys": []string{
        "File.Trimmed", "Feature", "Object.Notation",
    },
}

err = tmpl.Execute(w, templateData)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error executing template:", err)
    return
}
```

This will keep the content printed as an ordered manner.